# removeRange() function gives empty string in Swift 2

Tags: swift2

The removeRange: is giving me an empty string in **Swift 2** and I don't understand why. 
The example in the apple documentation is:

```
var welcome = "hello!"    
let range = welcome.endIndex.advancedBy(-6)..<welcome.endIndex
welcome.removeRange(range)
//I get "" as result rather than "hello" where the exclamation mark is removed
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I wonder, why do you think the result is wrong? What is your expected result? To remove the exclamation mark, you should use `-1`, not `-6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start at the `endIndex` and then you go *back* by 6. You are now at the beginning of the word. Then you make a range to the end index and you remove the content of this range: of course there's nothing left. :)

For example, it could be this instead:

```
var welcome = "hello!"
let range = welcome.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)..<welcome.endIndex
welcome.removeRange(range)
```

Or this:

```
var welcome = "hello!"
let range = welcome.startIndex.advancedBy(5)..<welcome.endIndex
welcome.removeRange(range)
```

There's many possible combinations.

Comment: Man that's the example straight from Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: But looks like you re right, maybe a typo in the documentation from Apple

Comment: You missed a step. In "Inserting and Removing" they add " there!" to "hello", making it "hello there!"... then they use your example on this. Their example works ok. :)

Comment: @irkinosor Be careful which set of documentation you're using. The one you linked to is the prerelease version for Swift 2.2, here are the [current (v2.1) docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html). You can tell which ones they are since the prerelease ones have `/prerelease` after `/library`.

Answer (score 1):

the string in apple documentation is
at the time of remove range

var welcome = "hello there!"

Comment: The original string is `var welcome = "hello"` but they modify it before they remove the range. At the time of using `removeRange` the string is `"hello there"

Answer (score 0):

The value of welcome.endIndex is 6 so advancedBy(-6) means it goes to 0. Then the range = 0..<6 that means the the range cover the whole string.
If you want "hello" then change only advancedBy(-1).

```
var welcome = "hello!"
let range = welcome.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)..<welcome.endIndex
welcome.removeRange(range)
```